# Notice: Undefined index:

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to edit a field in db, somehow i able to get the data from the db into a table and then i display an EDIT button is every row, whenever someone click on any edit button, it gets the id of that row and display all the result in the next page, and change the value accordingly and save the result.

Issue is when i am trying to save that result it shows me an error

> Notice: Undefined index: Is_6_Port_Antenna in C:\xampp\htdocs\LTE\index_edit.php on line 67

Here is my code, I pretty sure there is something wrong with my SQL table, but still need an ides from you guys !!

```
if (isset($_POST['button'])) {


         $ltesitename = $_POST["LTE_Site_Name"];
         $sitecode = $_POST["Site_Code"];
         $ltecellcode = $_POST["LTE_Cell_Code"];
         $region = $_POST["Region"];
         $city = $_POST["City"];

         $phase = $_POST["Phase"];
         $subphase = $_POST["Sub_Phase"];
         $latitude = $_POST["Latitude"];
         $longitude = $_POST["Longitude"];
         $type = $_POST["Type"];
         $portantenns = $_POST["Is_6_Port_Antenna"];

         $lteetitlspre = $_POST["LTE_E_Titls_Pre"];
         $lteetitlspost = $_POST["LTE_E_Titls_Post"];
         $ltemtitlspre = $_POST["LTE_M_Tilts_Pre"];
         $ltemtitlspost = $_POST["LTE_M_Tilts_Post"];
         $lteazimuthpre = $_POST["LTE_Azimuth_Pre"];
         $lteazimuthpost = $_POST["LTE_Azimuth_Post"];

         $lterfheightpre = $_POST["LTE_RF_Height_Pre"];
         $lterfheightpost = $_POST["LTE_RF_Height_Post"];
         $antennatypelte = $_POST["Antenna_Type_LTE"];
         $lastauditdate = $_POST["Last_Audit_Date"];
         $activityowner = $_POST["Activity_owner"];
         $comments = $_POST["Comments"];
```

It only shows the error for **Is_6_Port_Antenna, LTE_E_Titls_Pre, LTE_E_Titls_Post , LTE_M_Tilts_Pre, LTE_M_Tilts_Post** and **Activity_owner**

I double cross check their name in my database....

Comment: Check the names in the `form`.

Comment: Chk your form is this input avaible or not Is_6_Port_Antenna other field as well

Comment: @A-2-A Yes, i use Var_dump() on these values , And i got NULL, but on other values i got the required value

Comment: @devpro Yes all the input fields are there

Comment: Match the names of input fields

Comment: Means from your form these values are not coming, either `name` attribute is not correct for those fields or you are not filling the values for those fields.

Comment: @A-2-A Thanks, there was issue with my name in the form

Comment: @BilalZafar you can mark and up-vote the answer for others help thanks.

Comment: @BilalZafar please mark and up-vote the answer for others help.

Comment: @BilalZafar its really bad that after asking you are not marking the question. I am deleting my answer.